# Java: Converting a char to a string

Tags: java

I have just done this in eclipse:

```
String firstInput = removeSpaces(myIn.readLine());
String first = new String(firstInput.charAt(0));
```

However, eclipse complains that:

> The constructor String(char) is
>   undefined

How do I convert a char to a string then??

Thanks

### EDIT

I tried the substring method but it didn't work for some reason but gandalf's way works for me just fine! Very straightforward!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what "didn't work"? What error message did it give you?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Easiest way?

```
String x = 'c'+"";
```

or of course

```
String.valueOf('c');
```

Comment: Worked and I understand it. :) It seems a little strange though, maybe because its too easy!

Comment: Concatenating 'c' to "" is less desireable as it uses StringBuilder. String.valueOf is the preferred approach.

Comment: @Steve - maybe, maybe not.  It depends on how smart the compiler is.  The JLS allows a Java compiler to rewrite String concatenation expressions to the most efficient equivalent code sequence.

Comment: @Stephen I used javac and javap (1.6.0_10) and `'C'+""` results in using StringBuilder. So while the JLS may allow rewriting, the Sun compiler doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of...

```
String first = new String(firstInput.charAt(0));
```

you could use...

```
String first = firstInput.substring(0,1);
```

[`substring(begin,end)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) gives you a segment of a string - in this case, 1 character.

Answer (score 3):

```
String x = String.valueOf('c');`
```

That's the most straight forward way.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use substring?

```
String first = firstInput.substring(0, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String firstInput = removeSpaces(myIn.readLine());
String first = firstInput.substring(0,1);
```

This has an advantage that no new storage is allocated.

Comment: -1 - FALSE.  New storage **is** allocated to represent the String object created by substring.  `String.valueOf(char)` *potentially* doesn't allocate any new space ... if the char is less than 127 and you've already called `valueOf` for that char.

Comment: @Stephen. TRUE. At least with Sun SDK. It uses package private String constructor that does offsets magic on the same `char[]` array that `firstInput` is using.  Please check SDK source code for that.

Comment: @Alexander. The private String constructor returns a new String object, so NEW STORAGE IS BEING ALLOCATED. On a 32 bit JVM, it is at least 4 words + the object header overhead.  Jeez ...

Comment: @Stephen. I've added a reply to your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829421/java-converting-a-char-to-a-string/1829684#1829684. I don't know what JDK you are using, but with regards to Sun 1.6, you cannot go from `char` to `String` without allocating `String` at runtime. `substring` at least does not allocate a new `char[]` array for internal storage. Jeez...

Comment: @Stephen. After you've deleted your wrong answer, have a decency to remove your slandering comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
String s = Character.toString('k');
```

Comment: That just calls `Character.valueOf('k')`

Comment: No it doesn't - not at all, it calls String.valueOf(char);